# alarm manager phone rebot

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am working on an app that should reappear after every 15 days, my app is working correctly, but what will happen if the phone reboots, I am using broadcast manager to restart the activity. But is there any way that the alarm remain at the same value e.g. if phone reboots after 3 days of previous event, then the next alarm should fire in 12 days.

I haven't seen this exact question, people generally ask about broadcast receiver, which I am already done. Any pointers?

Is storing the alarm time in a file is a good idea? But then what goes in `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*14` ? My sample alarm manager is below:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*15, pi);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to save the value in SharedPreferences and restart the app with a modified alarm.

I'd save the value at some interval and also detect phone shutdown (using broadcasts)

Answer (score 0):

Yes alarm will get cleared once the device is rebooted.From the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running. Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), **but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.**

You can register `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver and re-schedule your alarm.You can store the time to be schedule either in shared preference or database.